# Apache VirtualHost with authentication, websockets

Tags: apache, websocket, apache2, virtualhost

I'm running a Spotify server on my Raspberry Pi at my school's robotics shop. It's on the school wifi network and it's accessed through a webpage http://localhost:6680. I wanted to add basic HTTP authentication (username/password) because people were being malicious, so I'm using an Apache VirtualHost as a proxy with basic authentication.

In addition, the webserver requires WebSockets to function through the same port. I successfully set up a VirtualHost file and it's working fine... except it's not working on Safari or iOS. After looking in the console, all WebSocket requests in Safari are returning a 401 error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://XX.XXX.XX.XXX/iris/ws/' failed: Unexpected response code: 401
```

After looking into this more, apparently [it's a known bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=80362) with Safari. Here's the VirtualHost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  <Proxy *>
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyRequests On

  ProxyPass /mopidy/ws/ ws://localhost:6680/mopidy/ws/
  ProxyPassReverse /mopidy/ws/ ws://localhost:6680/mopidy/ws/

  ProxyPass /iris/ws/ ws://localhost:6680/iris/ws/
  ProxyPassReverse /iris/ws/ ws://localhost:6680/iris/ws/

  <Location />
    ProxyPass http://localhost:6680/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:6680/

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Content"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there any way we can simply remove authentication for *just* the websockets but not for the webpage? Considering how this is structured, that should be the case, but it isn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about WebSockets, but I do know that you should always declare the VirtualHost port you are listening to if you want to separate traffic.

Try to do so by adding two different VirtualHost in the same configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  <Directory "/">
    AllowOverride All
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Content"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

From now on I can't help further:

```
<VirtualHost *:6680>
 somethingsomethingsomething
</VirtualHost>
```

## Update

Traffic different from :80 is blocked in your school, I guess.
I can suggest a more radical approach which is banning all traffic from Safari (both desktop and mobile).
You can modify the config by adding a redirect to a courtesy page like "your browser is not supported".

```
 <Location *>
 SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*Safari* bad_browser
 Deny from env=bad_browser
 </Location>
```

Comment: I don't want it to be hosted on port 6680, I want it to be proxied from 6680 to 80, with http authentication but no authentication on ws. Your example proxies to both port 80 and port 6680 which is not what I'd like to do.

Comment: edited my post with a small integration, I hope this helps

Comment: This is not an answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are proxying over your websockets if needed. They might look something like this:

```
ProxyPass        /socket.io http://localhost:6680/socket.io
ProxyPassReverse /socket.io http://localhost:6680/socket.io
```

Comment: I do this in lines 11-15.

Comment: right sorry didn't notice. Any luck on what might be happinging? Wierd how its only not working on IOS browser your say. I've dealt with sockets but didn't have this issue. I was having a problem with cross-origin headers and proxies.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. It's an issue with WebSockets requiring authentication. All browsers except Safari send authentication headers when they make a ws request, so I just want to disable the requirement for authentication for all ws requests. I still haven't figured it out.

Comment: Not sure how you application is set up. You should just be able to request login information to access application to protect. I do not see why the web socket would need to be authenticated. If the user password is correct allow them to render webpage else re-authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

Try do next, like described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/227130/http-authentication-exceptions):

```
#In your case it will be like this:
<LocationMatch /(iris|mopidy)/ws>
  Allow from all
</LocationMatch>
```

Update: Please be aware this rule to wide as you see.

Comment: This doesn't work, unfortunately. No additional errors or anything, I just appended this to the end of my VirtualHost file and the same issue persists.